# Add mongodb cluster to a replica set

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have a database db on mongodb server `s0` with collection `coll` which is not sharded. To shard this collection I set up a sharded cluster and add `s0` to replica set `rs0`. Now I want to add the sharded cluster to this replica set `rs0` so that on replication the collection gets sharded in the cluster. But mongos cannot be added to a replica set. How do I add this cluster to `rs0`?

Note: I am aware of the other way to shard an existing collection but there are downtime considerations in that approach.

Comment: The current description isn't entirely clear. Can you confirm: `s0` is a member of a replica set  `rs0` and you want to copy an unsharded collection from this replica set into a sharded collection in another deployment with minimal downtime? Also, what version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: I think have mixed terms node, replica set, cluster, shard... From single node, you can start building replica set, that requires boot (restart) of node once. Cluster infrastructure (config servers, mongoS) can be build "background", without interference to replica set or clients.  Replica set can be connected to cluster (as shard) without downtime, but client must be restart, so it connects to mongoS and not directly to replica set. Additional replica sets (shards) can be then added to cluster without any down time. As can collection be sharded without downtime.

Comment: @Stennie Yes. That is what I meant. MongoDB version - 3.4.6

Answer (score 0):

First you [convert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/) your standalone node to replica set and you add two other nodes, so it is real replica set (one node RS is possible, but not really RS)

Cluster must have more than one RS.. It's not cluster if you have only one shard...

Then you start to build your [cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/) by deploying config server replica set and at least one mongoS.

When cluster infrastructure is ready, you connect your replica set(s) to that cluster.

Now you can enable sharding of one or multiple db/collections.

Or you can move existing data to (ready made) cluster with [mongo-connector.](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector)

Comment: I want to set up the replica just to shard the collection without impact on existing server. What you have mentioned would be basically same as sharding the existing collection on existing setup.

Comment: "Sharding the collection" means that you are partitioning collections data to multiple servers. Of course you can always build cluster (bunch of shards) and replicate data from already existing node/replica  with mongo-connector https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector

Comment: The answer makes sense after the edit. Will check out mongo connector.

Comment: ..and when mongo-connector approach works.. Don't for get to vote my answer. :)  Even I understood what you meant first wrongly.